# Golang Unit test matrix not visible on SonarQube dashboard

Tags: go, sonarqube

Problem Statement - SonarQube's dashboard does not show the Unit test matrix which should be available next to the Coverage matrix

Jenkins Plugin SonarQube Scanner -

```
sonar.projectBaseDir=/home/jenkin/workspace/github.com/company/project/src
sonar.projectKey=sonar_projectname
sonar.projectName=sonar_projectname
sonar.projectVersion=${BUILD_NUMBER}
sonar.go.coverage.reportPaths=cover-all.out
sonar.go.gometalinter.reportPaths=static-analysis.out
sonar.go.tests.reportPaths=test-report.json
sonar.sources=.
sonar.sources.inclusions=**/**.go 
sonar.exclusions=**/vendor**, **/*.xml
```

Note: Offical Document https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Go+Coverage+Results+Import

Here is a screenshot of the dashboard missing the unit test matrix:

[image: SonarQube Dashboard missing the unit test matrix missing]
[SonarQube Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDGot.png)

Answer (score 2):

sonar properties has these keys missing :

```
sonar.tests=.
sonar.test.inclusions=**/**_test.go
```